# How to Change Background Color of TableRow in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I Created one Table, While MouseMove occured, I want to Change Background Color of TableRow,
and also when MouseLeave happen, it will back to old color of TableRow.
Here is coding, but it's not working.

```
currentRow.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(ShowRowColor);
currentRow.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(HideRowColor);

void ShowRowColor(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e){
        TableRow tr = sender as TableRow;
        ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
        animation.From = (tr.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color;
        animation.To = Colors.Indigo;
        animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        tr.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty,animation);
    }

    void HideRowColor(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e) {
        TableRow tr = sender as TableRow;
        ColorAnimation animation;
        animation = new ColorAnimation();
        animation.From = Colors.Indigo;
        animation.To = (tr.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color;
        animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        tr.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty,animation);
    }
```

Please Help me...

Answer (score 0):

You will want to start the animation on the `Background` property of the `TableRow` because you need to target the `Color` property of the `SolidColorBrush`

Example:

```
tr.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
```